# How can I fix the error popup “Class not registered”

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application builds without errors. But when I run my application, I get an error popup saying "Class not registered".

My teammembers, accessing the same remote server, don't have this issue

This is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/class-not-registered-pops-up-as-an-error-message/f22077ff-0df6-446e-8b8a-d82c42d33533?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

when we are running our project, First we have to select which browser our project need to run. If we select by default 'Launch Windows App' through 'browse with' option for any landing page, then above error will come.

**For Resolve:-**  Fallow below steps

Select Landing file name =>righ click on file name=> select 'browse with' option=> then select google chrome or any browser and click on set as default.

Now you solution will may work.